# NbClust with one cluster

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataset that I split by specific parameters and run `NbClust` function to calculate optimal number of clusters. Every once in a while there is only one cluster and `NbClust` breaks with

> Error in sample.int(m, k) : cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

Is there a generic workaround? Thanks!!
Data are attached:

```
df1 = structure(c(-0.01400863, -0.01400863, 0.00712136, 0.01377456, 
0.00712136, 0, 0, -0.00636396, 0, 0.00636396), .Dim = c(5L, 2L
))

nb = NbClust(data = df1, diss = NULL, distance = "euclidean",
        min.nc = 2, max.nc = 10, method = "kmeans",alphaBeale = 0)
```

EDIT (8/15/2018). I have found a solution to the problem. It simply bypasses the `NbClust` checks if `nrow(unique(df1)) < 5` since `max.nc` must be at least `min.nc + 2`.

```
    n_clusters = nrow(unique(df1))
if (nrow(unique(df1)) > 4) {
  nb = NbClust(data = df1, diss = NULL, distance = "euclidean",
               min.nc = 2, max.nc = min(nrow(unique(df1)),10), method = "kmeans",alphaBeale = 0)
  n_clusters = max(unlist(nb[4]))
  print(n_clusters)
}

clusters = kmeans(df1,n_clusters)
```